# Tamaño de una cadena

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una función para leer la cantidad del caracter `"\"` que se encuentra en una cadena para luego separar cada frase entre el caracter buscado y almacenarlas en un array.

en la prueba que estoy realizando pongo parte del path donde está una imagen solo que al momento de ver la cadena en la consola no me sale el caracter `"\"` y se ponen todas las palabras juntas.

a continuación presento el código de lo que estoy ejecutando en el javascript:

```
function prueba(nombre){
    console.log(nombre);
    var tam = nombre.length;
    console.log(tam);
}
```

y en el html está la siguiente línea:

```
<h3 onclick="javascript:prueba('Users\HTML\img')">aqui</h3>
```

tienen idea de que puedo hacer para que se pueda leer el caracter `"\"`

Comment: Sería bueno que coloques el string que estás ingresando y la salida que esperas, porque la parte del **""** está un poco ambigua.

Comment: bueno en unos minutos ya actualizo la pregunta xq recién estoy empezando a hacer la función

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres decir que al pasar por parámetro la cadena 'Users\HTML\img' pierdes el carácter "\".

Deberías agregar otra contra barra quedando así:

```
<h3 onclick="javascript:prueba('Users\\HTML\\img')">aqui</h3>
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que el carácter \ tiene un significado especial en Javascript (y en muchos otros lenguajes: se usa para indicar caracteres especiales. Por ejemplo:

- `\n`: Es la forma de representar una nueva línea.
- `\t`: Es la tecla Tab(ulador).
- `\xHH`: Representará al caracter con código Unicode HH. Si el carácter tiene un código muy grande es posible que necesites algo como `\xHH\xHH`.
- `\\` : Representa al caracter `\`
- Puedes mirar la lista de caracters escapados [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#notaci%C3%B3n_de_escape)
- Otro carácter que no esté en la lista y esté detrás de `\` es ignorado, porque no tiene un significado especial.

Por tanto, tu código realmente está mostrando algo distinto a lo que crees:

```js
function prueba(nombre){
    console.log(nombre);
    console.log(nombre.length);
}
```

```html
<h3 onclick="javascript:prueba('Users\HTML\img')">aqui</h3>

<h3 onclick="javascript:prueba('Users\\HTML\\img')">Con los caracteres "escapados"</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con la función "split" de javascript lo podes hacer perfectamente ya que te devuelve un arreglo.

```
var cadena = "Users\\HTML\\img";
var array = cadena.split("\\");
// ["Users","HTML","img"]
```

Podes acceder a este link para conocer más de la función.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: gracias, ya pongo en práctica lo que me comentas

Comment: Ese código no funciona correctamente

Comment: Sí, lo acabo de notar, funciona si ponemos `var cadena = "Users\\HTML\\img";` y `var array = cadena.split("\\")`

Comment: Puedes [edit] para corregir la respuesta